# LM317... Do we need resistors?

Tags: circuit-analysis, voltage-regulator, lm317, calculation

In the circuit below, I replaced LM1117 with LM317. Do I need to add resistors at the output terminal? and how can I calculate the output voltage in this case?

[image]

Comment: FWIW you can buy similar regulators that output 5v automatically without requiring the feedback resistors.  For common voltages like 5v these are usually more convenient.

Comment: Also worth noting (since we know nothing about the load) that the LM317 may require at least 0.5V more dropout voltage than the LM1117.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LM317 needs resistors to set the output voltage, so yes, you need resistors.

The method of calculating resistor values are in the LM317 datasheet, you seem to just need 5V output.

Comment: What and which frequency will your loop of wire get its power from?

Comment: @Audioguru The power will be transposed from a transmitter circuit to the receiver ^^.

Comment: No say no details. Most transmitters are for radio and TV very high and ultra high frequencies that your 1N4001 diodes do nothing. Are you making a wireless charger??

Comment: Right --- 1N4001 are the worst possible diodes to be using --- WWWWAAAAYYYYY too slow!!!!    OP should be using Schottky diodes or other fast recovery devices.

Comment: @Audioguru yes, I am trying to make a wireless charger.

Answer (score 0):

Your 10 turns coil with no ferrous core will simply be a very high current heater at a low frequency but will be a good 50MHz radio transmitting coil that needs a radio station license.

In Google I asked for Inductive Charger Circuit and found a project at Silicon Chip magazine 9 years ago. It operates at 12.9kHz with coils that are tuned with a capacitor and have hundreds or thousands of turns but use a short distance between the transmitting and receiving coils and air as the core:
https://www.nutsvolts.com/magazine/article/august2013_Bates